# My silver pickaxe got damaged. How is it possible?

Tags: terraria

I crafted my first silver pickaxe in Terraria 1.1. I did not examine its stats until some time later. The name color is grey with -14% damage.

I have no problem mining with it but killing monsters especially cave bats (which I have been doing a lot) got weaker.

Can anyone give an insight into why this happened?
I am split between weapon degradation and crafting fluke.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You just got unlucky crafting it. "Damaged" is a [random modifier](https://terraria.wiki.gg/wiki/Modifiers) (which decreases damage) assigned to items when they're crafted or drop from monsters. Similar negative modifiers, such as "Broken" and "Shoddy", also exist.

Apart from making a new one, there's not a whole lot you can do about it at this point in the game.

However, later on (after you've defeated your first [Goblin Army](https://terraria.wiki.gg/wiki/Goblin_Army)), you can find and rescue the [Goblin Tinkerer](https://terraria.wiki.gg/wiki/Goblin_Tinkerer), who allows you to reforge weapons, tools and accessories, for a price. By then, you'll likely have a different, way better pickaxe, though.

Comment: I'll just sell it and craft another. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @AugustusThoo Is it really that big a deal? I mean, pickaxes are mostly for digging. You could craft a Silver Broadsword instead. Cheaper, and does more damage.

Comment: Getting 'damaged' items from crafting is a big of a deal to me.

Comment: Since you aren't likely to do much fighting with you pickaxe, this is a non-problem. That modifier only refers to damage done to enemies.

Comment: It's less efficient than other, better modifiers you might get otherwise, but not a huge loss.  You can craft a new one if you're scrapped for a good digging tool and hope for a better modifier.  "Quick" or other aspects that make it go faster tend to be best for pickaxes.